# Getting a file icon solely from a given MIME-type (no file itself) in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, mime-types, qfileinfo

Ok, I know about the class [`QFileIconProvider`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileiconprovider.html). I also know about [`QMimeType`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimetype.html) (and [`QMimeDatabase`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedatabase.html)). But I am surprised that I cannot find a simple connection between the two.

So what I need is to get an icon used by the operating system for a given type of files. Normally, this is done like this:

```
QIcon icon = QFileIconProvider().icon(QFileInfo("/path/to/some.file"));
```

But what if I want to get an icon without reference to a particular file, just for a given MIME type? Say, my application uses attached files and syncs across multiple devices; on some devices the attached file might be absent, but I know the MIME type of that file, so I still want my app to show the proper file icon, using only the MIME type info.

As a temporary solution, I found that if I pass a non-existing file to QFileInfo in the code string above, it does retrieve a correct icon (obviously, purely from the extension of that non-existing file), at least in Linux. But this method is not documented, and there is no guarantee it will always work.

So I need something that could work as the non-existing method  `QFileIconProvider().icon(QMimeType &)`.

Comment: [`QMimeType::iconName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimetype.html#iconName-prop) might possibly be of use.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that. But the only way to use the return value of this function is to pass it to `QIcon::fromTheme()` which, however, works only in X11, and my app is supposed to be cross-platform (in fact, even in Xubuntu 16.05 this function returns a string like "application-pdf", but `QIcon::fromTheme()` does not produce a valid icon).

Comment: Well, not quite.  It only works by *default* on `X11` systems.  But as stated in the docs. if you want to use it on other platforms "...you will have to bundle a compliant theme in one of your themeSearchPaths() and set the appropriate themeName()."  So it's extra work but certainly (I think) do-able.